# Meaning and usage of 〜してからにしろ

Tags: grammar, particles, imperatives

From the manga *yotsubato!*, casual conversation:

> 早く寝るのはいいけど、せめて晩飯食って風呂入ってからにしろ

In this sentence how does からにしろ at the end change it? I know the full sentence means this:

> It's ok to go to bed early, but at least eat dinner, and take a bath.

But wouldn't that be

> 早く寝るのはいいけど、せめて晩飯食って風呂入る。

I'm guessing that しろ is the imperative form of する, から is `from`, and に is the directional particle. But I don't see how that changes the sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Dictionary form: 「Te-form of Verb A + から + に + する 」
>
> Imperative form: 「Te-form of Verb A + から + に + しろ（or せよ） 」

This is a common set phrase meaning "Do (something) only after doing A."

The translation you provided is passable but is certainly not a very literal one.

> 「[早]{はや}く[寝]{ね}るのはいいけど、せめて[晩飯]{ばんめし}[食]{く}って[風呂]{ふろ}[入]{はい}ってからに**しろ**。」

In this sentence, 「しろ」=「寝ろ」. but the translation does not clearly says it.  It is only implied successfully because "Verb A" here happens to be 「寝る」 so the reader will know that one would have to do everything else (eat dinner and take a bath, in this case) before going to bed.

A highly literal translation would be:

> "It is OK to go to bed early, but ***do so*** at least after eating dinner and taking a bath."