# what does に in this sentence actually mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> エアコンを掃除するときは、安全上、必ずコンセントを抜いてから**に**してください

I know  this sentence means that you should pull out plug first if you want to clean air conditioner, but what does this に mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and usage of 〜してからにしろ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/meaning-and-usage-of-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%82%8d) - the meaning is "do B only after doing A"